# What is the meaning of indexPath?

Tags: iphone

I'm new to iPhone development.
I try to operate the tableview.
So I saw some sample codes and books.
But I don't understand what is the meaning of `indexPath`.

Here is a line of code.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ;
```

Please explain for me he `indexPath` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The NSIndexPath class represents the path to a specific node in a tree of nested array collections.

A table has sections and rows, to know where a row is you need to know the index of which section it is in and the index position it is at within that section.

`UIKit` adds a category to make it easier to work with `UITableView`'s.

```
@interface NSIndexPath (UITableView)

+ (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRow:(NSInteger)row inSection:(NSInteger)section;

@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSInteger section;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSInteger row;

@end
```

Answer (score 5):

It contains the section number and the row number of the cell in question. You can write `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row`.