# Swift and core data - Array and cell basics

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, core-data, swift

If I define my array as:

```
var myList: Array <AnyObject> = []
```

and then use the viewDidLoad override function to populate this array like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "List")

    myList = context.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil)!
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and my "List" only contains usernames as strings. What exactly is being stored in "myList"? Is it just as simple as an array of strings with the usernames?

Any thoughts and explanations would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You really have two questions here. The good news is that the second one is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807827/what-is-the-meaning-of-indexpath. Can you take that part out, and we'll work on answering the first question?

Comment: @dpassage thank you, very helpful. The first question has been taken out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myList` would contain subclasses of `NSManagedObject` or `List` instances if you have defined that class. Each object would have attributes that you have defined for that core data object.

The `indexPath` is a class that is used to represent the `row` and `section` of the `UITableView`. This is also used to identify the `item` and `section` of a `UICollectionView`.

Comment: So if I have defined my objects as Attribute: username and Type: String, my array would consist of strings?

Comment: No, it would be an array of `NSManagedObject`s. To get the NSString, you would use the accessor: `[myList objectAtIndex:i].username` where `i` is the index number of the item you need.

Answer (score 1):

`executeFetchRequest` returns an array of *managed objects* from the CoreData data store. There are basically two ways to handle them.

The first is to use them as-is. They will all be instances of `NSManagedObject`, and you can use methods like `valueForKey:` to get their values.

The second way is to define your own subclass of `NSManagedObject`, in your case probably named `List`, and then define properties on that object allowing you to access the values directly.

Core Data as a whole is both insanely powerful and insanely complex. I strongly recommend you work through a tutorial, either [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) or [otherwise](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift), to get a hang of it. (Note that some of Apple's docs recommend starting with something called *Core Data Starting Point*. Helpfully, Apple has retired that document, but hasn't yet removed the references to it from other documents.)